# make songs list in Windows Phone 8.1 with xaml and c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I'm trying to fill a listBox with songs name found in media library but since 8.1 removed MediaLibrary Class i searched other methods but using this, the first istruction throws me an unhandled exception.. maybe access denied.. i don't know.

```
StorageFolder musicFolder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await GetFilesAsync();
```

Comment: You might try catching the exception and outputting it somewhere so you can check the problem?

Comment: System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Comment: [SOLVED] Sorry I forgot to edit my AppxManifest so I didn't give the right permission for music library !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[SOLVED] Sorry I forgot to edit my AppxManifest so I didn't give the right permission for music library !!